# Getting whole row value if checkbox is checked in datagrid C#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, selected

I'm trying to write a code for getting 3 values from textboxes if some of checkboxes in same row is checked.
Anyone know an easy(or hard) way to do this?

My datagrid looks like this: [image]

I have Load button that finds a file of specific type(XML.config) somewhere in file system, after that I'm calling a method that gets some strings from that file, find substrings of them and put them in 3 separated lists. Those values are in datagrid as Type, MapTo and Name.
I accomplish this by putting all 3 lists in one ObservableCollection and after that I'm sending that ObservalableCollection to datagrid like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>> _obsCollection = new   ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>> MyObsCollection
{
    get { return _obsCollection; }
}
tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;
```

This is XAML code that shows binding:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,265,0,0" Name="tabela" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="556" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="Binding MyObsCollection">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="122" Binding="{Binding Item1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MapTo" Width="122" Binding="{Binding Item2}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="121" Binding="{Binding Item3}"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Controller">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataGridChecked}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Service">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataGridChecked}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Injection">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataGridChecked}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

What I'm practically trying to is to accomplish looping thou all 3 columns containing checkboxes to see which of them are selected and if any of 3 in same row is selected then I need to send all 3 string values from that row to some variable. 
Anyone can help me with this. For instance I don't know how to get isSelected property from checkbox in data grid.
I was doing a lot of researching and all that I was able to find was examples for DataGridView, and almost nothing for DataGrid.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>>` - You should really create a proper strongly typed Data Model instead of that monstrosity, please.

Comment: @HighCore thanks for commenting... I'm still a beginner and I don't know how to do that...Do you maybe know some good links or tutorials about creating a Data Model? I know this kind of code is messy but I'm still trying crazy things and exploring them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Tuple` create your own class, say `RowData` with all the properties you want to show as columns:

```
public class RowData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //implement INotifyPropertyChanged

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string MapTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Controller { get; set; }
    public bool Service { get; set; }
    public bool Injection { get; set; }
}
```

change `ObservableCollection` to use your type

```
public ObservableCollection<RowData> MyObsCollection { get { .... } }
```

and set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` on `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid 
   Grid.Column="0" 
   Grid.RowSpan="2" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
   Height="206" 
   Width="556" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="12,265,0,0" 
   Name="tabela" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding MyObsCollection}"/>
```

and then to get items where any of 3 `CheckBoxes` is selected you do:

```
var selectedList = MyObsCollection.Where(n => n.Controller || n.Service || n.Injection).ToList();
```

Comment: @dkozi I did everything like that but now I get empty datagrid with only one row. Should I leave all the bindings of textbox rows as they use to be, and should I bind checkbox rows with Controller, Service and Injection properties?

Comment: Did it, binding was wrong of course, cause now I have new names and Item1, Item2 and Item3 could not be used for binding anymore. Thank you very much on your help.

Answer (score 0):

**To get the Checked item row  from DataGrid and add it into list**

```
      List<string>chzone=new List<string>();//Declare it as globally,
      //Note: if DataGrid is Binded as ,Datagrid.Itemsource=dt.defaultview;
      //If datagrid contain the Checkbox, get the checked item row and add it into list
      private void DataGridcheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var checker = sender as CheckBox;           
            if (checker.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var item = checker.DataContext as DataRowView;
                object[] obj = item.Row.ItemArray;//getting entire row
                chzone.Add(obj[0].ToString());//getting row of first column value
            }
            else //This is for Unchecked Scenario
            {
                var item = checker.DataContext as DataRowView;
                object[] obj = item.Row.ItemArray;
                bool res = chzone.Contains(obj[0].ToString());
                if (res == true)
                {
                    chzone.Remove(obj[0].ToString());//this is used to remove item in list
                }
            }

        }
```